# TV movie: Man travels in a kind of tank with a robot woman

Tags: story-identification, movie

The only thing I remember is that the main character and travels with a woman in a kind of tank in a post-apocalyptic world. At some point, the robot woman is hurt and broken… (you can see some led light in her face). The man fires up the tank.

It was a movie. I show it on TV. Should be from the eighties. Also is a real action movie.

About the characters. The girl was not blonde for sure. They use rifles and shotguns..

The van/tank had a upper round trap door and a side door. It was armored.

Then man and the robot had some kind of relationship... even sex.

While not damaged, the girl had nothing visually identifying she as a robot.

Comment: This is very terse at the moment, could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in anything else you may remember? For example, what media was this? Novel, short story, film, TV show etc. When did you see it? Was it new then? Do you remember the looks of the characters that could help us track this down. Every little thing can help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. Done.

Comment: This makes me think of _Damnation Alley_ by Roger Zelazny but too many elements don't _quite_ fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scenes that you describe sound like [Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086346/), which was released in 1983.

Some other details that you might remember:

- The protagonist was on a mission to rescue three women who had crash landed on the planet and had been captured a warlord named Overdog.
- A vehicle superficially resembling a sailing ship, but travelling on a railway track. It was attacked by bandits, and it was at the end of this battle that the protagonist discovered that his android companion had been fatally damaged.

Comment: I have looked for the film and it' the one I was looking for. :)